# Select 4 buttons with the same CSS class

Tags: c#, css, selenium

Then I try this, and it runs ok:

```
 driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".follow-text")).Click();
```

but only the first runs ok, how can i select the second button which has the same css ".follow-text"?

adding number [2] does not works for me:

```
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".follow-text")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".follow-text[2]")).Click();
```

Any help will be apreciatted

Answer (score 1):

Your XPATH is extremely dependent on the order of the classes.  Some frameworks might put one class before the other and change it each time the page renders.  Take at look at one of your xpath selectors.

```
//button[@class='user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button btn small small-follow-btn']
```

This matches on:

```
<button class="user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button btn small small-follow-btn">
```

What if it was outputted as?:

```
<button class="user-actions-follow-button btn small follow-button small-follow-btn">
```

Now your selector is completely useless as it is heavily reliant on the word order.  If you use CSS, you can use `.` as such:

```
By.CssSelector("button.user-actions-follow-btn.btn.small.follow-button.small-follow-btn")
```

This selector does not care which order the classes are in, as long as it contains all the classes in some order.

If you need more information on this, check out [this page](http://ddavison.github.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html) and it might help on formulating effective CSS selectors for Selenium

Comment: share the actual html source, then maybe i can help

Comment: Then I try this, and it runs ok:

 driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".follow-text")).Click();
but only the first runs ok, how can i select the second button which has the same css ".follow-text"?

adding number [2] does not works for me:

        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".follow-text")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".follow-text[2]")).Click();
Any help will be apreciatted